# jsTree not rendering with "inline" json data

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I've been struggeling with jsTree for days. It's so simple but nothing is happening. Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#TreeView2").jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "data": [{
            "data": "A node",
                "metadata": {
                id: 23
            },
            "children": ["Child 1", "A Child 2"]
        }, {
            "attr": {
                "id": "li.node.id1"
            },
            "data": {
                "title": "Long format demo",
                "attr": {
                    "href": "#"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", ]
}).bind("select_node.jstree",

function (e, data) {
    alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id"));
});
});
```

Straight forward and right out of the book. Here's the markup result though:

```
<div id="TreeView2" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default">
     <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Nothing is rendered but the classes on the div container. Same if I retrieve the json data from an ajax post. Nothing. Not even an ajax post is registered in my console. No errors either. **The plugin works if I run it with inline html markup as data source.** As in existing markup.

The script is in a document.ready function. The markup to begin with is just a div with an ID. All plugin scripts are loaded correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think someone edited my question just 1 sec before I edited myself. Might have over written the changes. You may make your changes again sir :)

Comment: :) ... i was just formatting for you.

Comment: I have a fiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/9wBET/  but I dont understand this issue...

Comment: @Nix - Ah man wtf. You didnt change anything did you? That is weird

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `$("#TreeView2").jstree`

Comment: @Nix - I've updated the question. Note again that the plugin works if I run it on existing markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the jstree documentation, besides being very weak and at times non existing, its pure outdated disinformation and very wrong. The example in the question is taken from their documentation/examples. I had to completely rewrite the whole thing. **The main reason the jstree didnt even render, was the lack of multiple plugins such as "ui" and "types".** I basically found the information on how to get it to work with dynamic json data etc. from 10 different sites and guides.

Answer (score 2):

Change your script to run `onLoad.`

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/9wBET/

Comment: like onload on the body dom or document? Doesn't work either. I've tried with jQuery 1.9.1 and 1.7. Nothing :( Maybe its because its in a Umbraco based app?